# Inequality with nested summations

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

I am struggling with proving the following inequality. Let $i,j\in \mathcal{J}$ and $b\in \mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{J}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are not overlapping sets. Think of $\mathcal{J}$ as locations and $\mathcal{B}$ as age groups, for example. Then we also have $0\leq p_j^b\leq 1$, $0\leq s_j^b\leq 1$, $\sum_j p_j^b = 1$ for all $b$, and $\sum_b s_j^b = 1$ for all $j$.

I want to show that:
$$
\sum_b p_i^b \sum_{j\neq i} p_j^b s_j^b \leq \frac{1}{4}.
$$
I know that $p_i^b \sum_{j\neq i} p_j^b = p_i^b(1-p_i^b)\leq 1/4. $

In case the inequality it's not true, I would also be happy with an alternative upper bound. Thanks.